# Encontrar y tildar checkbox de un nodo en un treeview

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un treeview con toda la estructura de directorios y archivos de la PC donde se está ejecutando la aplicación. Al iniciar, obtengo una lista de strings con varias rutas, para las cuales necesito encontrar el nodo del treeview correspondiente a cada una de ellas y marcar su checkbox.

El problema es que al iniciar la aplicación, sólo aparecen en el treeview las unidades (discos fijos y extraibles) y a medida que voy expandiendo cada nodo se va completando con sus subdirectorios (esto lo plantee así para no recargar el inicio de la aplicación). Entonces lo que no encuentro forma de hacer es, primero ir expandiendo los nodos hasta llegar al último nivel de cada ruta (puede ser archivo o directorio), y segundo, marcar su checkbox.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

Al iniciar la aplicación:

```
foreach (DriveInfo unidad in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (unidad.DriveType != DriveType.Fixed && unidad.DriveType != 
        DriveType.Removable)
    {
        continue;
    }

    TreeNode raiz = new TreeNode(unidad.Name);
    raiz.ToolTipText = "Unidad";
    raiz.Tag = unidad.Name;
    raiz.ImageIndex = 0;

    raiz.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
    tvArbol.Nodes.Add(raiz);                                                
}
```

Al expandir un nodo:

```
DirectoryInfo directorioPadre = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] subDirectorios = directorioPadre.GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectorio in subDirectorios)
{
    TreeNode directorioHijo = new TreeNode(subDirectorio.Name);
    directorioHijo.Tag = subDirectorio.FullName;
    directorioHijo.ImageIndex = 1;

    directorioHijo.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
    directorioHijo.Checked = nodo.Checked;
    nodo.Nodes.Add(directorioHijo);
}

List<FileInfo> archivos = new List<FileInfo>();
archivos.AddRange(directorioPadre.GetFiles());

foreach (FileInfo archivo in archivos)
{
    TreeNode archivoHijo = new TreeNode(archivo.Name);
    archivoHijo.ImageIndex = 2;

    archivoHijo.Tag = archivo;
    archivoHijo.Checked = nodo.Checked;
    nodo.Nodes.Add(archivoHijo);
}
```

Comment: Creo que tienes que usar un método recursivo para llenar tu `TreeView`. Este es un [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970580/4092887), pero antes de implementarlo, te sugiero entender el código y en caso de que no se ajuste a lo que intentas lograr, te recomiendo buscar _si no o has hecho_ `c# fill treeview with directories` o preguntas similares.

Comment: No termino de comprender tu problema. Si ya sabes como expandir los nodos, cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que tienes una `List<string>` con las rutas de varios archivos. Entonces entiendo que tienes que ir marcando como `Checked` las rutas que coincidan a medida que vas expandiendolas.

Aqui tienes un método que comprueba si hay que añadir el `Checked` a un nodo. Seguro que puede optimizarse y yo probablemente lo convertiría en un método de extensión, pero para que te hagas una idea **(*paths* es la lista de las rutas, cambialo por la tuya)**.Utiliza el `Level` del nodo para saber hasta que parte del path hay que comparar:

```
private bool isChecked(TreeNode node)
{
    bool check= false;
    foreach (string pathcomparar in paths)
    {
        string[] splittedPath = pathcomparar.Split(new char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] splittedTreePath = node.FullPath.Split(new char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (String.Join("\\", splittedPath.Take(node.Level + 1)) == String.Join("\\", splittedTreePath.Take(node.Level + 1)))
        {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Con este método, no tienes mas que modificar tu código de la siguiente manera.

*Al iniciar la aplicación:*

```
foreach (DriveInfo unidad in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (unidad.DriveType != DriveType.Fixed && unidad.DriveType !=
        DriveType.Removable)
    {
        continue;
    }

    TreeNode raiz = new TreeNode(unidad.Name);
    raiz.ToolTipText = "Unidad";
    raiz.Tag = unidad.Name;
    raiz.ImageIndex = 0;

    raiz.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
    tvArbol.Nodes.Add(raiz);
    raiz.Checked = isChecked(raiz);
}
```

*Al expandir nodos (entiendo que usas el evento AfterExpand):*

```
DirectoryInfo directorioPadre = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] subDirectorios = directorioPadre.GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectorio in subDirectorios)
{
    TreeNode directorioHijo = new TreeNode(subDirectorio.Name);
    directorioHijo.Tag = subDirectorio.FullName;
    directorioHijo.ImageIndex = 1;

    directorioHijo.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
    //directorioHijo.Checked = nodo.Checked;
    nodo.Nodes.Add(directorioHijo);

    directorioHijo.Checked = isChecked(directorioHijo);
}

List<FileInfo> archivos = new List<FileInfo>();
archivos.AddRange(directorioPadre.GetFiles());

foreach (FileInfo archivo in archivos)
{
    TreeNode archivoHijo = new TreeNode(archivo.Name);
    archivoHijo.ImageIndex = 2;

    archivoHijo.Tag = archivo;
    nodo.Nodes.Add(archivoHijo);

    archivoHijo.Checked = isChecked(archivoHijo);
}
```

Si tienes alguna duda o problema, comentamelo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si bien no fue la solución (porque probablemente me expliqué mal) sí me sirvió para llegar a la solución que buscaba.